# TouchesBegan overriding touchUpInside actions

Tags: iphone, ios5, uibutton, touchesbegan

I've implemented a custom UIButton and in order for me to handle LongPress events (without using Gesture Recognizers) I had to use `touchesBegan:`, `touchesEnded:` on my class. Problem is that now the regular button events aren't working. I'm wondering what's causing this and how I could avoid it?

The touch based events are working but the previous actions I had for `touchUpInside:` are no longer functional.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use `touchesBegan:` for longpress, use this gesture recognizer!

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longTap:)];
[view addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
[longPressGesture release];

-(void) longTap:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    NSLog(@"gestureRecognizer= %@",gestureRecognizer);
    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSLog(@"longTap began");
    } 
}
```

Comment: I want to avoid that. Gesture recognizers limit my iOS target audience. I want to move away from it.

Comment: what do you mean? gesture recognizer are already there since iOS3.2! Nobody uses 2.0 anymore.. almost everyone in the world is at least on iOS 4.0!

Comment: Some requirements I can't get past by :P

Comment: As a side note, would the long press recognizer continue firing? I would need to update a slider as long as the button is pressed down. StateBegan would only fire once. And StateChange would only fire if I move my finger while holding the button. So all and all I would probably have to use a timer fire event

Comment: the long press recognizer only fires once as long as you keep holding it down. If you need to do that slider-thing than yeah, you probably need touchesbegan and touchesended. Still, UIButtons and touchesbegan and touchesended should work at the same time..